# Changing custom List view row background color

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have an application with a custom list view which has a textview and an image(delete), when I click the image the background color of that row should change and when I click the same image again its background should change to default color. I'm able to change the background color but only once, Im not able to change it twice, I mean Im not able to revert back to its default color.

Here is my code ...

**CustomListView.java**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    holder = null;
    DataFields rowItems = (DataFields) getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_field_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.dataFields = items.get(position);
        holder.mName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmFieldName);
        holder.mDeleteImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmFieldDeleteImage);
        holder.mDeleteCheck = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmFieldDeleteCheck);
        holder.mDeleteMainRL = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmFieldMainRL);
        holder.mDeleteImage.setTag(position);

        final View clickView = convertView;
        holder.mDeleteImage
                .setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int status = 0;

                        HomeActivity.mDeleteFieldLL
                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        HomeActivity.hmAddField
                                .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        holder.dataFields = items.get(position);

                        if (mFieldId.size() == 0) {
                            mFieldId.add(holder.dataFields);
                            ++count;
                            HomeActivity.hmDeleteSelected
                                    .setText("Delete (" + count + ")");

                            clickView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.list_row_bg);

                        } else {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mFieldId.size(); i++) {
                                if (mFieldId.get(i).getId() == holder.dataFields
                                        .getId()) {
                                    status = 1;
                                }
                            }

                            if (status == 0) {
                                mFieldId.add(holder.dataFields);
                                ++count;
                                HomeActivity.hmDeleteSelected
                                        .setText("Delete (" + count + ")");

                                clickView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.list_row_bg);

                            } else if (status == 1) {
                                mFieldId.remove(holder.dataFields);
                                --count;
                                if (count < 0)
                                    count = 0;

                                clickView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.list_row_bg_default); //doesnt changes back to default color

                                HomeActivity.hmDeleteSelected
                                        .setText("Delete (" + count + ")");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mName.setText(rowItems.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

And one more problem is, that background color is not the color I mentioned in color.xml, I tested by putting different colors but when I click the image that color is changing to only one particular color.

So, to put it simple, I need to change the background color of listview row when I click the image and revert back to the default color when I click it again.

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: would you show the code just that is relevant to your problem, it is hard to understand the giving code with all your classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the color may already changed, but you make mistake at setBackgroundColor(), so it seem like the color is not changing.

For the color problem try using this code

```
clickView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_row_bg));
```

You have to pass Context object when instantiate adapter.

or you can use something like

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```